# How to parse svg polyline data from url using JSON.parse() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I simply want to parse some data of this svg from this url:`http://colorillo.com/bxys.inline.svg`
When I view the source of the page. I would like to parse the `points` and `stroke` data and send it to google's console using console.log()

My code is shown below, this is what I tried to do but had no luck of getting it to print into the console.

```js
    var url = new url("http://colorillo.com/bxys.inline.svg");

    url = function(e) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
    var points = JSON.stringify(obj.points)
    var stroke = JSON.stringify(obj.stroke)
    }

    console.log(points)
    console.log(stroke)
```

Comment: Is the `new url()` meant to be the native browser `URL()` constructor or some other constructor?

Comment: I'm not sure. I was told that this would help retrieve the data. I've simply added it. It gives me a error in google's console when I try to run this script. I just need to read the data and print it into console.

Comment: URL() only parses the url string, it does not get the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various problems with your code, like defining `url` twice.  You probably want to use the `fetch` API to get it.  You'll have to run your code on colorillo.com or rehost the file on your own server, because they haven't set up CORS to allow you to access the file from another website.

SVG is a dialect of XML, not JSON.  You need to use a DOMParser:

```
// Create request to fetch the SVG file.
xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
// Tell the request where the file is.
xhr.open("GET", "http://colorillo.com/bxys.inline.svg");
// Add event handler to process the file once it's been fetched.
xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // Once the text is available, create an XML parser
  // and parse the text as an SVG image.
  const xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
    this.responseText.trim(), 
    "image/svg+xml"
  );
  // xmlDoc.getElements() returns something Array-like, but not an Array.
  // This turns it into an Array.
  const polylines = Array.from(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('polyline'));
  console.log(polylines.map(
    pl => [
      // Parses each 'points' attribute into an array of pairs of numbers
      pl.getAttribute('points').split(' ').map(
        pair => pair.split(',').map(x=>+x)
      ),
      // Various stroke information

      // Convert rgb(R,G,B) to #RRGGBB
      // Leading hash, then pull out the digits with a regex
      '#' + pl.style.stroke.match(/rgb\((\d*), (\d*), (\d*)\)/)
        // Throw away everything but the digits
        .slice(1,4)
        // Convert to a number, render in hex, uppercase, pad with 0s
        .map(x=>(+x).toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2,'0'))
        // Concatenate the hex digits
        .join(''),
      +pl.style.strokeWidth,
      pl.style.strokeLinejoin,
      pl.style.strokeLinecap
    ]
  ));
});
xhr.send();
```

Comment: I never used xpath or DOMParser :( I don't know how to make it print the data still.

Comment: Please help me get it to print. :( I thank you for helping me so far. It looks like it would do something more then my code. I just don't know how to make it print using your code.

Comment: OK, added code to fetch the points and stroke data, print it, and comments on everything.

Comment: I noticed it changes the stroke color into a RBG format and not the original. Anyway to make it into hex? when it prints the ``pl.style.stroke``

Comment: The rgb(R, G, B) comes from the file.  I've written code to change that format to #RRGGBB format.